# How to prove a distribution is or is not heavy tailed?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution, heavy-tailed

I've seen the definition for a distribution that has a heavy right tail but I can't seem to prove to myself that a distribution has a heavy right tail or not.
How would you prove that for the normal and for the log-normal distribution?

Comment: Apply the definition: it only requires estimating an integral.  For additional ideas, see the analyses at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86429 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168851.

Comment: Any chance for guidance on applying the limit on this integral for the definition?

Comment: Apply the definition and use the fact that for any $t\gt 0,$ eventually (for sufficiently large positive $x$) $tx \gt (\log x)^2 + \epsilon x$ for some $\epsilon \gt 0.$  (You can take $\epsilon=t/2$ for instance.)